# Comparing multiple columns in two different excel sheets

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to compare two columns in two separate excel files and output the similarities in a third sheet in powershell

I was able to execute this for one column but I am not able to do it for two

```
$snowFile = Import-Csv C:\sample\test_sheet2.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name  
$nistFile = Import-Csv C:\samples\other_sheet2.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $snowFile -DifferenceObject $nistFile -IncludeEqual 
               -ExcludeDifferent | Select-Object InputObject | Export-Csv 
               -Path C:\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Over here I am using `ExpandProperty` for one column -Name, I have to do it for another column called Version. If both Name and Version are equal across the two files, that entire row (of file 2) has to be outputted in a third file. I am new to `PowerShell` can you please help me with this problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: You can omit the `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` for the CSV imports and provide for the `Compare-Object` the parameter `-Property` to specify what properties you like to compare.

Comment: Hi, Using -Property is not giving me the comparison results i.e the similarities, it is just outputting the entire column.

Comment: I'm pretty unsure if I've got what you mean. If possible you could post some sanitized rows of both CSV files to test. You might re-read [mcve]. (Please update your question with additional data if needed. Do not add it as comment or answer. Thanks)